# sas make directory with mnemonic in the folder name

Tags: sas

I'm trying to create a folder with the character "&" in the name

I've tried the %superq function which seems to interpret correctly the macro variable

```
x "cd     c:\Users\avibe_000\Dropbox\htdocs\Landa2018\LDPdepartments\";                                                                 
data _null_;                                                                                                                            
call symput('mv1','Smith&Jones');                                                                                                       
 run;                                                                                                                                   
%let testmv1=%superq(mv1);                                                                                                              
%put  &testmv1  ;                                                                                                                       
x "mkdir &testmv1";
```

The code works but creates a folder "Smith" and not "Smith&Jones" as expected

Answer (score 1):

The `DCREATE` function will create a sub-folder.  In macro use `nrstr` to pass a non-resolved value to the function.  `%SUPERQ` is not, pre se, for value assignment, but for as-is value retrieval based on macro variable name.

```
filename parent 'C:\Temp';
%put NOTE: parent(path)=%qsysfunc(pathname(parent));

%let rc = %qsysfunc(DCREATE(%nrstr(Smith&Jones),parent));

filename sj 'C:\Temp\Smith&Jones';
%put NOTE: sj(path)=%qsysfunc(pathname(sj));
```

Answer (score 1):

The macro processor tries to process macro triggers inside of double quotes. But it doesn't inside of single quotes.   Also the Windows command line will need quotes around the value with an `&` in it.

```
>mkdir a&b
'b' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

>mkdir "a&b"
```

So change your process to enclose the command in single quotes and the directory name in double quotes.

```
data _null_;
  call symputX('command',quote('mkdir "Smith&Jones"',"'"));
run;
x &command ;
```

Answer (score 1):

@Tom Nice answer.
And you just been so closed to your own way:

```
data _null_;
    call symput('mv1','d:\Users\avibe_000\Dropbox\htdocs\Landa2018\LDPdepartments\Smith&Jones');
run;

%let testmv1=%str(%")%superq(mv1)%str(%");
%put &testmv1;
x mkdir &testmv1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `mf_mkdir` macro in the SASjs [macrocore](https://github.com/sasjs/core/blob/main/README.md) library - this also uses `dcreate()` and recursively creates any subdirectories that are needed.  It is also delivered as a macro function (so can be used pretty much anywhere in your code).

```
/* import and compile (or go there and copy paste into your code */
filename mc url "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sasjs/core/main/base/mf_mkdir.sas";
%inc mc;

/* execute */
%mf_mkdir(/tmp/this %nrstr(&) that)
```

result:

[image]